# If and else condition not work in controller in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

My controller:

```
public function getid() {
  $userid = Auth::user()->id;
  // $result = PersonalInfo::where('id',$userid )->get();
  $result =   DB::table('finacial_info')->where('userid',$userid )->pluck('userid'); 
  if ($result!=$userid ) {
    return view('investor.Investor2',compact('id','result'));
  } else {
    return redirect('Investor3');
  }
}
```

In this condition user id is exists but else part is not working.

Comment: [‘*Not working*’, eh?](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: __pluck()__ returns an _array_

Answer (score 1):

Add `use Redirect;` in the top of your controller. And change the ´return redirect´ to ´return Redirect::to´.

Hoep this helps you out